# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in angular forms

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular application which consists of one parent component ( products) designed for listing the details using pagonation  and child  component Product details to view the details of individual products for which i have used angular forms. The form page is loading the data correctly from the restful api
But in addition i am getting the below error in the console when ever i navigate from listing page to Individual product detail display page, I could not able figure out the reason for this error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ProductDetailsComponent_Template (product-details.component.html:7)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12210)
    at refreshView (core.js:12049)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13499)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11770)
    at refreshView (core.js:12105)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13445)
    at refreshView (core.js:12076)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13499)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11770)
```

Code Details are below:

Mapping model class to map the response form restful api

```
export interface productDetailsData{

    id:number;
    items:string;
    brand:string;
    colour:string;
    size:string;
    type:string;
}


export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  idval:number;
 productDetail:productDetailsData;

  constructor(private router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute,private randomUser:RandomuserService){
    this.route.params.subscribe((param:Params) =>{
      this.idval=+param['id'];
      console.log(this.idval);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.randomUser.getIndividulProductDetail(this.idval).subscribe(data => {
      /*** fetching the details from api *****/
      this.productDetail={...data};
      console.log('the data form response ',this.productDetail);
      
   });
  }


  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
   console.log(form.value);
   this.productDetail={...form.value};
   console.log(this.productDetail);
   this.randomUser.saveData(this.productDetail).subscribe(data => {
     console.log('successfully stired'); });
  }
}



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  
    <div class=" .col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group" >
       <label for="id">ID</label>
       <input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" ngModel name="id" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.id">
        </div>
         
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="id">ITEMS</label>
         <input type="text" id="items" class="form-control" ngModel name="items" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.items">
         </div>
                 
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="brand">Brand</label>
        <input type="text" id="brand" class="form-control" ngModel name="brand" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.brand" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="colour">COLOUR</label>
        <input type="text" id="colour" class="form-control" ngModel name="colour" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.colour">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="size">size</label>
        <input type="text" id="size" class="form-control" ngModel name="size" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.size">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type">TYPE</label>
        <input type="text" id="type" class="form-control" ngModel name="type" [(ngModel)]="productDetail.type">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
    </div>   
    </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **`productDetail`** as *ngModel* which means that it's Two way binding.

So it's start evaluating `productDetail` once the view is initialized where initial value of it is **undefined**, hence the error.

Try to initialize it in *constructor* or in *ngOnInit* like below,

```
this.productDetail = {} as productDetailsData;
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be getting that error because `productDetail` does not have a value initially.
Either initialize it or use the [Elvis operator](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/) (?) like below:

```
<input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" ngModel name="id [(ngModel)]="productDetail?.id">
```